# What is the difference in using @OneToMany vs @ManyToOne to the otherside for the same relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables: Student and Address. A student has many addresses and I am trying to use @OneToMany on the Student table. A question came into mind what if I use @ManyToOne on the Address table to mention that one Address belongs to Many Students. Please help my clarify my concern.

Comment: There are two moving parts to JPA - how the database schema looks and how the Java classes look. In a `OneToMany <-> ManyToOne` relationship, the database will have a foreign key on the "many" side - i.e. every address will have a `student_id`; this doesn't really change. On the Java side, you can have a `List<Address>` on the `Student` and/or a `Student` on the address. These fields need to be annotated to tell JPA that they form part of a mapped relationship. Then comes the question of relationship owner and inverse relationships...

Comment: ... In short, this question is too broad for this site and I would suggest you find a tutorial.

Comment: Well both are needed for a Relationship:

 **A OneToMany relationship in Java is where the source object has an
 attribute that stores a collection of target objects and if those
 target objects had the inverse relationship back to the source object
 it would be a ManyToOne relationship.**

Comment: @Gatusko no need to shout...

Comment: @Gatusko "both are needed for a Relationship" - not for unidirectional relations ;)

Comment: Regardless of the title of the question, what you need is @ManyToMany on both sides of the relationship if `a stundent has many addresses` and `an address belongs to many stundents`.

Answer (score 7):

1. A single Student has three addresses say Address1, Address2 and Address3.
   [image]

   [image]

The Relationship model for above will be, say Student id is a primary key in Student and will act as a foreign key in Address:-
[image]

Then in your Address class, you will define this relationship as below:-

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name ="STUDENT_ID")
 private Student student;
```

We use @OneToMany and  @ManyToOne, two different annotations, so that we are able to tell Hibernate *which object is the child/many part of the relationship and which object is the parent/one side of the relationship.*

We are able to tell Hibernate which object is the parent object by assigning the @OneToMany annotation to the appropriate getter method… and which object is the child object by assigning the @ManyToOne annotation to the appropriate getter method.

> Hence, Address becomes child side of relationship and Student becomes
>   parent side of relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You might even use both if it makes sense. Basically you define in which direction the relation is navigable, e.g. if a student has an address you'll probably want to be able to navigate from that student to her address. However, an address might be shared by multiple persons which are not only students so the relation on that side might be different (or not needed at all).

Whatever you decide there's one thing you should keep in mind: you should define *one* side of the relation to be the owner (owning side) as otherwise you'd confuse Hibernate and get unexpected results. If there's only one side (i.e. Student->Adress but not the other way round) it's easy, if you got both sides you need to declare one the owning side - in most cases this will be the "many"-side, i.e. where you put the `@ManyToOne`. The other side must be declared as non-owning or you get two owning sides, e.g. by adding `mappedBy="name_on_owning_side"` to `@OneToMany`.

Example:

```
class Student {
  @ManyToOne
  Address address;
}

class Address {
  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "address" )
  Set<Student> residents;
}
```

Here `Student` is the owner of the bidirectional relation (which allows you to navigate `student->address` and `address->resident(student)` ) and only changes to `Student.address` would be written to the database.

A final note: as you can see that's quite a complex topic so you might want to have a look at some tutorial, e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany